# C++ - Using enum declared inside a class in the class contructor's call

Tags: c++, enums

I am new in C++ and I made a class header (PID.h) that looks like this:

```
class PID
{
public:
    PID(double newSetpoint,
        double newOutputMax,
        PID::Direction newDirection,
        PID::Mode newMode,
        PID::Reference newReference);

    enum Direction { DIRECT = 0, REVERSE = 1 };
    enum Mode { MANUAL = 0, AUTOMATIC = 1 };    
    enum Reference { LINEAR = 0, CIRCULAR = 1 };  

    // class continues...
};
```

Visual Studio 2010 shows Direction, Mode and Reference in the class constructor marked with an error saying "Class PID has no memeber Direction" (same for the other two).

In the PID.cpp it marks the constructor name in red saying

**error C2511: 'PID::PID(double,unsigned int,double,double,double,double,double,PID::Direction,PID::Mode,PID::Reference)' : overloaded member function not found in 'PID'**

Does anyone know what is happening? Why can't I call the class's constructor with a enum declared inside the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your enums before you use them (when used outside of a member function body**):

```
class PID
{
public:

    enum Direction { DIRECT = 0, REVERSE = 1 };

    enum Mode { MANUAL = 0, AUTOMATIC = 1 };

    enum Reference { LINEAR = 0, CIRCULAR = 1 };  


    PID(double newSetpoint /*...lots of stuff more to initialize*/, double newOutputMax, Direction newDirection, Mode newMode, PID::Reference newReference);

    // class continues...
```

Also, you do not need to qualify your enums when using them inside the class scope.

** "when used outside of a member function body" means that something like the following would be valid:

```
class PID
{
public:
    void someMemberFunction() {
        Direction d = DIRECT;
        ...
    }

    enum Direction { DIRECT = 0, REVERSE = 1 };
    ...
```

Comment: `You need to declare your enums before you use them` _when used outside of a member function body_

Comment: This worked! thanks! Could you just clarify the "when used outside of a member function body" ?

Comment: got it, C++ is not declarative so it reads the .h in a linear fashion so if it wasnt declared it cant know what it it is just like in the .cpp